# How to set uitextfield auto suggestion labels programatically

Tags: ios, objective-c, autosuggest

I have seen the auto suggestion for iOS text fields. I would like to set the auto suggestion labels filtered from an `NSArray` I have. Is it possible in that auto suggestion for a particular textfield? If yes, how can I achieve this?

Sample image:

[image]

I need to show those suggestions (ie: appl,Apple and apple) from my NSArray.

I am using Xcode (Objective- C).
Thanks.

Comment: Are you looking for UITextField "placeholder"?

Comment: https://github.com/EddyBorja/MLPAutoCompleteTextField . Your welcome :)

Comment: @MendyK: Thanks for the comment but I am not looking for a suggestion dropdown list. I would like to access the native UI suggestion over the Keyboard as in picture. Thanks.

Comment: I doubt you could access them from the native keyboard. Your best bet is probably to create your own keyboard.